# how to define manifest file in order to use GCM services

Tags: php, android

i am beginner all around the using of the Google cloud messages api, and i have a problem that i succeed to send the message but i am not get it on my device.
i saw that some manifest contain section of "" should i use that?

this is the GCM server:

```
   <?php

class GCM {

    function __construct() {

    }
    /**
     * Sending Push Notification
     */
    public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
        // include config
        include_once 'connection.php';

        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data'             => array("message" => $message),
        );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' .GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;
    }
}
?>
```

this is the manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.matant.gpsportclient"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.matant.gpsportclient.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />





    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.matant.gpsportclient.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />



    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.matant.gpsportclient.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.galaxystech.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Controllers.ForgotPassword"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Controllers.Login"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Controllers.SignUp"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_screen" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Controllers.InviteUsersActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_invite_users" >
        </activity>

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name=".GoogleCloudNotifications.GCMMessageView"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_gcmmessage_view" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is the GCMhandler:

```
    package com.example.matant.gpsportclient.GoogleCloudNotifications;

/**
 * Created by matant on 10/28/2015.
 */
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.R;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;


public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCM Tutorial::Service";

    // Use your PROJECT ID from Google API into SENDER_ID
    public static final String SENDER_ID = "84627XXXXXXX";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onRegistered: registrationId=" + registrationId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onUnregistered: registrationId=" + registrationId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent data) {
        String message;
        // Message from PHP server
        message = data.getStringExtra("message");
        // Open a new activity called GCMMessageView
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GCMMessageView.class);
        // Pass data to the new activity
        intent.putExtra("message", message);
        // Starts the activity on notification click
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        // Create the notification with a notification builder
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gpsport_logo_icon)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle("Android GCM Tutorial")
                .setContentText(message).setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .getNotification();
        // Remove the notification on click
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(R.string.app_name, notification);

        {
            // Wake Android Device when notification received
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            final PowerManager.WakeLock mWakelock = pm.newWakeLock(
                    PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "GCM_PUSH");
            mWakelock.acquire();

            // Timer before putting Android Device to sleep mode.
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    mWakelock.release();
                }
            };
            timer.schedule(task, 5000);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context arg0, String errorId) {

        Log.e(TAG, "onError: errorId=" + errorId);
    }
}
```

this is the result that i got from the server:

```
"multicast_id":7010046538768109204,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446032848127257%e63ae1e0f9fd7ecd"}]"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Google provide a sample you can check link

[link](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- [START gcm_permission] -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<!-- [END gcm_permission] -->

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->

    <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->
    <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

define permission above  tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.theengager.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

      <receiver
        android:name="com.xyz.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="your package name" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.xyz.GcmIntentService" />
</application>
```

GcmIntentService.java

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

// Intent home_screen = null;
String check = "";
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    if (!extras.isEmpty()) { // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                    + extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                .equals(messageType)) {

            check = extras.getString("message");
            if (check != null) {
                sendNotification(check);
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
        }
    }
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(String msg) {

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager
            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("New Message").setContentText(msg)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

}
}
```

GcmBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
 } 
}
```

Comment: what is com.doctorapp. in the uses permission? and i am using a jar file so i dont actually have a file under the name "GcmBroadcastReceiver.java"

Comment: it is my package name